# Flink error: Specifying keys via field positions is only valid for tuple data types

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using the Scala API of Flink. I have some transformations over a `reports = DataStream[Tuple15]` (the `Tuple15` is a Scala Tuple and all the fields are `Int`). The issue is located here:

```
reports
  .filter(_._1 == 0) // some filter
  .map( x => (x._3, x._4, x._5, x._7, x._8))
      (TypeInformation.of(classOf[(Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)])) // keep only 5 fields as a Tuple5
  .keyBy(2,3,4) // the error is in apply, but I think related to this somehow
  .timeWindow(Time.minutes(5), Time.minutes(1))
  // the line under is line 107, where the error is
  .apply( (tup, timeWindow, iterable, collector: Collector[(Int, Int, Int, Float)]) => {
       ... 
  })
```

The error states:

```
InvalidProgramException: Specifying keys via field positions is only valid for 
tuple data types. Type: GenericType<scala.Tuple5>
```

Whole error trace (I marked the line pointing to the error, line 107, corresponding to the `apply` method on the code above):

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: Specifying keys via field positions is only valid for tuple data types. Type: GenericType<scala.Tuple5>
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.operators.Keys$ExpressionKeys.<init>(Keys.java:217)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.operators.Keys$ExpressionKeys.<init>(Keys.java:208)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.keyBy(DataStream.java:256)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream.keyBy(DataStream.scala:289)
here -> at du.tu_berlin.dima.bdapro.flink.linearroad.houcros.LinearRoad$.latestAverageVelocity(LinearRoad.scala:107)
    at du.tu_berlin.dima.bdapro.flink.linearroad.houcros.LinearRoad$.main(LinearRoad.scala:46)
    at du.tu_berlin.dima.bdapro.flink.linearroad.houcros.LinearRoad.main(LinearRoad.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

But this doesn't make sense to me. I **am** using a tuple type, am I not? Or what is the deal with the `GenericType<...>`?

And how should I fix the `map` to make the `keyBy` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the `TypeInformation` belongs to the Java API and, thus, does not know the Scala tuples. Therefore, it returns a `GenericType` which cannot be used as the input for a `keyBy` operation with field positions.

If you want to generate the Scala tuple type information manually, you have to uses the `createTypeInformation` method which is contained in the `org.apache.flink.api.scala`/`org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala` package object.

But if you import the package object, then there is no need to specify the type information manually, since the `TypeInformation` is a context bound of the `map` operation and `createTypeInformation` is an implicit function.

The following code snippet shows the idiomatic way to deal with `TypeInformations`.

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._

reports
  .filter(_._1 == 0) // some filter
  .map( x => (x._3, x._4, x._5, x._7, x._8))
  .keyBy(2,3,4) // the error is in apply, but I think related to this somehow
  .timeWindow(Time.minutes(5), Time.minutes(1))
  // the line under is line 107, where the error is
  .apply( (tup, timeWindow, iterable, collector: Collector[(Int, Int, Int, Float)]) => {
       ... 
  })
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, but I don't fully understand your answer. I am now importing `import org.apache.flink.api.scala.createTypeInformation` and 
`import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.createTypeInformation`, but they don't get used and there is no improvement.

Comment: You mustn't import both of them, because then the Scala compiler cannot resolve the context bound because it knows two identifiers which can produce the `TypeInformation`.

Comment: I have also try both of them individually and nothing happens... They don't even get used, as IntelliJ displays them in grey instead of the normal color for used imports.

Comment: I just understood, by chance really, what you mean by `there is no need to specify the type information manually` (please see my own answer). If you would kindly edit your answer to make this clearer to future readers of this thread, I'll be happy to accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered the same problem and able to fix it as follows:

Use Tuple2 class from Flink API i.e., **[import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple15]** instead of **scala.Tuple15**

Please see your import section and correct it.

Here I used **Flink Java API**. In case of **Scala**, **import org.apache.flink.api.scala._** package

[Apache Flink]

Answer (score 1):

Well, after much time spent, I actually got it to work simply by removing the `TypeInformation`. So, changing this:

```
.map( x => (x._3, x._4, x._5, x._7, x._8))(TypeInformation.of(classOf[(Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)]))
```

to this:

```
.map( x => (x._3, x._4, x._5, x._7, x._8))
```

Nonetheless, I assume this solution is kind of a hack, because I'm still getting warnings (well, INFO logs) from Flink:

```
00:22:18,662 INFO org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor - class scala.Tuple15 is not a valid POJO type
00:22:19,254 INFO org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor - class scala.Tuple4 is not a valid POJO type
```

So, if there is any more general answer, I'll be happy to accept it. Until then, this worked for me.

**UPDATE**

I had tried this before and didn't work. I just realised that now it's working thanks to the answer from @Till. So, *as well as* what I stated, you need to import **either** `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.createTypeInformation` or `org.apache.flink.api.scala.createTypeInformation` (*not both!*).

Answer (score 0):

AggregateOperator support only Flink Tuple. if you are facing this issue then first please check your import is it **scala.Tuple2** then it's wrong . So it should be **org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2**